# printf does not print removing unrelated line fixes it

Tags: c

My Code does not print anything with gcc. I tried to flush the buffer, but does not make a difference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int foo[65];
    for(int i; i < 64; ++i) {
    printf("Number:  Count: \n");
    }
}
```

If remove the 3 line it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    for(int i; i < 64; ++i) {
    printf("Number:  Count: \n");
    }
}
```

Is this a bug in gcc because this array is not related to the printf call.

Comment: `i` is uninitialized resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: It is very common in C that code which has undefined behavior (like using the values of uninitialized variables) will change unpredictably when unrelated changes are made.  This is not in any way a bug in gcc; it's a bug in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching your code to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int foo[65];
  for(int i=0; i < 64; ++i) {
  printf("Number:  Count: \n");
  }
}
```

Which will just print the following 64 times:

```
 Number: Count:
```

Are you trying to print out the contents of your array foo[65]? If so that is also uninitialized so you'll need to insert integers first before you view them.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize i, otherwise it could be any random number. Unlike some other languages, C does not automatically initialize variables to 0 (or the equivalent) unless they are global variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int foo[65];
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
    printf("Number:  Count: \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: "C does not automatically initialize variables to 0" --> True for this code yet global `int`  variables are initialized to 0.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Global and static are initialized to zero by default.

Comment: Edited answer to include caveat for globals.